# Data structure with fast contiguous ranges retrieval

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Imagine data structure, that manipulates some contiguous container, and allows quick retrieval of contiguous ranges of indices, within this array, that contains data (and probably free ranges too). Let's call this ranges "blocks". Each block knows its head and tail index:

```
struct Block
{
    size_t begin;
    size_t end;
}
```

When we manipulating array, our data structure updates blocks:

```
    array view          blocks [begin, end]
--------------------------------------------------------------
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     [0, 9]

pop 2                   block 1 splitted

0 1 _ 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     [0, 1] [3, 9]

pop 7, 8                block 2 splitted

0 1 _ 3 4 5 6 _ _ 9     [0, 1] [3, 6] [9, 9]

push 7                  changed end of block 3

0 1 _ 3 4 5 6 7 _ 9     [0, 1] [3, 7] [9, 9]

push 5                  error: already in

0 1 _ 3 4 5 6 7 _ 9     [0, 1] [3, 7] [9, 9]

push 2                  blocks 1, 2 merged

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 _ 9     [0, 7] [9, 9]
```

Even before profiling, we know that blocks retrieval speed will be cornerstone of application performance.
Basically usage is:

- very often retrieval of contiguous blocks
- quite rare insertions/deletions
- most time we want number of blocks be minimal (prevent fragmentation)

What we have already tried:

1. `std::vector<bool>` + `std::list<Block*>`. On every change: write true/false to `vector`, then traverse it in for loop and re-generate `list`. On every query of blocks return `list`. Slower than we wanted.
2. `std::list<Block*>` update list directly, so no traversing. Return list. Much code to debug/test.

Questions:

1. Is that data structure has some generic name?
2. Is there already such data structures implemented (debugged and tested)?
3. If no, what can you advice on fast and robust implementation of such data structure?

Sorry if my explanation is not quite clear.

**Edit**

Typical application for this container is managing buffers: either system or GPU memory. In case of GPU we can store huge amounts of data in single vertex buffer, and then update/invalidate some regions. On each draw call we must know first and last index of each valid block in buffer to draw (very often, tenth to hundreds times per second) and sometimes (once a second) we must insert/remove blocks of data.

Another application is a custom "block memory allocator". For that purpose, similar data structure implemented in "Alexandrescu A. - Modern C++ Design" book via intrusive linked list. I'm looking for better options.

Comment: I've often though of developing such a "discrete range" type based on a tree or vector, but then heard that such a thing is already in boost.

Comment: Does your container contain ranges, or does it contain data at discrete ranges of indexes?

Comment: In our application, it must be some kind of wrapper over a simple buffer (dynamic array). I've added edit with GPU buffer use-case. For simplicity we can assume that underlying container is an `std::vector<Data>`. Buffer interface (read/write/update/mark free) is not hard to implement, but we've stuck at this "blocks".

Comment: +1 An interesting concept and question (boost implemented or not, it stokes the gray-matter =P )

Comment: @Mooing Duck, can you please show boost one? =)

Comment: May I know the size of the problem? Way to take care it may be different

Comment: @MMSC yes, I'm sure it is possible to make it differently. Previously we have no all-in-one buffers and no custom memory allocation at all. And I continuously thinking about other ways. Problem size can vary significantly: firstly, buffer can be small (bytes) then, after some reallocations, become huge (hundreds of megabytes, hence `size_t` for begin/end). Firstly you can have one block, which then can "randomly" split/merge. But most times we want to reduce blocks number, so it is probably tenth or hundreds.

Comment: Thanks @Drop! Another question: for this requirement - "very often retrieval of contiguous blocks", you need all the blocks or some of them? How you consume it? Use them one by one or pickup like blocks[i]?

Comment: @MMSC in case of GPU buffer we want all of `blocks.begin` and `blocks.end`, to pass to drawing function each frame.

Answer (score 5):

What I see here is a simple **binary tree**.
You have pairs (blocks) with a `begin` and an `end` indices, that is, pairs `(a,b)` where `a <= b`. So **the set of blocks can be easily ordered and stored in a search-binary-tree**.
Searching the block wich corresponds to a given number is easy (Just the tipical bynary-tree-search). So when you delete a number from the array, you need to search the block that corresponds to the number and split it in two new blocks. **Note that all blocks are leaves, the internal nodes are the intervals wich the two child nodes forms**.
Insertion on the other hand means searching the block, and test its brothers to know if the brothers have to be collapsed. This should be done recursively up through the tree.

Comment: Well, trees. Can you advice any suitable binary tree implementation? I don't trust me writing it from scratch. Probably `std::set` or `std::map` can be adopted?

Comment: @Drop the problem here is that `std::map` and `std::set` are trees, but are dessigned to work as associative containers. Our tree is not an associative container, is a binary-tree with custom data and behaviour. So you have to implement it from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try a tree like structure, either a simple red-black tree or a B+ tree.

Comment: Trees are great. And they are hard. Can you, please, clarify more about how to apply it to my case? Also, I'm not aware of any popular, robust, universal implementations of trees in C++. And writing/debugging/testing my own is not a good option.

Comment: @Drop A google search will get you more information than I'm willing to type.

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution (vector of bools + list of blocks) seems like a good direction, but note that you don't need to regenerate the list completely from scratch (or go over the entire vector) - you just need to traverse the list until you find where the newly changed index should be fixed, and split/merge the appropriate blocks on the list.

If the list traversal proves too long, you could implement instead a vector of blocks, where each block is mapped to its start index, and each hole has a block saying where the hole ends. You can traverse this vector as fast as a list since you always jump to the next block (one O(1) lookup to determine the end of the block, another O(1) lookup to determine the beginning of the next block. The benefit however is that you can also access indices directly (for push/pop), and figure out their enclosing block with a binary search.
To make it work, you'll have to do some maintenance work on the "holes" (merge and split them like real blocks), but that should also be O(1) on any insertion/deletion. The important part is that there's always a single hole between blocks, and vice-versa

Comment: Hmm, vector imitation of list sounds interesting. And I think this is huge memory trade off. But if we will maintain low fragmentation this solution is quite viable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a list of blocks? Do you need stable iterators AND stable references? boost::stable_vector may help. If you don't need stable references, maybe what you want is to write a wrapper container that contains a std::vector blocks and a secondary memory map of size blocks.capacity() which is a map from iterator index (which is kept inside returned iterators to real offset in the blocks vector) and a list of currently unused iterator indices.

Whenever you erase members from blocks, you repack blocks and shuffle the map accordingly for increased cache coherence, and when you want to insert, just push_back to blocks.

With block packing, you get cache coherence when iterating at the cost of deletion speed. And maintain relatively fast insert times.

Alternatively, if you need stable references and iterators, or if the size of the container is very large, at the cost of some access speed, iteration speed, and cache coherency, you wrap each entry in the vector in a simple structure that contains the real entry and an offset to the next valid, or just store pointers in the vector and have them at null on deletion.