# Make interval using two set<int>

Tags: c++, iterator, set, intervals

We want to use two `set<int>`s' to create some integer-intervals.

some of works we want to do is remove an interval that is in our intervals, but the set is sorted! and `interval_first[i] != set1[i]` , `interval_last[i] != set2[i]`.

as a way, how can we delete an inteval just using `set<int> st1, nd2` and `iterator it1, it2` ?

> **Sample input:**
>
> a 2 5
>
> a 3 4
>
> d 2 5
>
> p
>
> **result:**
>
> 1, 2
>
> 5, 5

I have this code now, and delete does not work (because set is sorted), please help me to complete this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> st1, nd2;
    while(true)
    {
        char order;
        cin >> order;
        int a, b;
        switch(order)
        {
        //Add:
        case 'a':
            cin >> a >> b;
            st1.insert(a);
            nd2.insert(b);
            break;
        //Delete:
        case 'd':
            cin >> a >> b;
            if(st1.find(a) != st1.end() && nd2.find(b) != nd2.end())
            {
                st1.erase(a);
                nd2.erase(b);
            }
            break;
        //Print:
        case 'p':
        {
            set<int>::iterator it1, it2;
            for(it1 = st1.begin(), it2 = nd2.begin(); it1!=st1.end(); it1++, it2++)
                cout << *it1 << ", " << *it2 << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**note:** nd2 means second and st1 means first!

Comment: Its homework or you could use a library?

Comment: If its the second case, checkout the [`boost::interval` library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm). If not, I remember a question I answered a couple of months ago about the implementation of intervals. The solution was the use of binary trees.

Comment: Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346174/data-structure-with-fast-contiguous-ranges-retrieval/

Comment: @Manu343726 We can use any library, but just with set(not vector or like that)...

Comment: So its homework and your teacher only lets you to implement it by yourself. Read the link, it has a possible solution to your problem